# reverse engineer ActiveRecord data model to jpa

Tags: java, ruby, jpa

are there any tools which would read a data model exposed via [ActiveRecord](http://ar.rubyonrails.org/) and generate equivalent data model using JPA?

note: We don't have any experience with ruby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge, there is no such tool and I'd suggest to generate the physical model from your active records and then to reverse engineer the physical model into JPA entities. This would work (and is IMO the simplest solution).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as pascal Thivent mentioned, you can generate a schema in the DB, then you can use a tool like Middlegen  to generate your Hibernate things, and from there - a short step to JPA, since JPA is largely based on Hibernate.